# Mock window.location.reload using Qunit

Tags: jquery, qunit

I want to mock `window.location.reload` object in success using qunit for below function:

```
function Test() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: /Test/TestMethod,
        data: 1,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8;',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.Successful)
                window.location.reload();
        },
        error: function (response) {
        }
    });
}
```

Can anyone help me mocking this peace of code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: window.location.reload, or window.*parent*.location.reload?

Comment: sorry it's window.location.reload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is JavaScript, you can override all functions and objects. To make things easier I would pass your function the `window` object to use. That way you can inject your a mocked window to use for your tests. If you use the code in production, you can either pass the real `window` object or simply call the function without the second parameter. The line `var currentWindow = currentWindow || window;` ensures that the global window is used, when you omit the parameter. The same is true for the callback, it is simply replaced by an empty function if you don't specify it.

Because you want to test an asynchronous call, you should use the [`asyncTest()`](http://api.qunitjs.com/asyncTest/) of QUnit. This enabled you to run your test code when the AJAX call returns. All you have to do is add a callback parameter to your code.
For your test you simply pass a callback method with test code and the mocked window. By defining the number of expected assertions (`expect(2)`), you make sure that both assertion are checked, i.e. if the code does not run the success method, you get an error, that the mocked `reload()` method was not executed.

The tested function:

```
function ajaxCall(callback, currentWindow) {
    var callback = callback || function() {};
    var currentWindow = currentWindow || window;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/',
        data: 1,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (response, statusCode) {
            if (statusCode === "success") {
                currentWindow.location.reload();
            }
            callback(statusCode);
        },
        error: function (response, statusCode) {
            callback(statusCode);
        }
    });
}
```

`window` mock:

```
module("AjaxTests", {
  setup: function() {
      this.mockWindow = {
          location: {
              reload: function() {
                  ok(true, "This mock function should be called");
              }
          }
      };
  }
});
```

The test:

```
asyncTest("ajaxCall with mock window", function () {
    expect(2);
    var testCallback = function(statusCode) {
        ok(statusCode === "success", "Response should be successful");
        start();
    }
    ajaxCall(testCallback, this.mockWindow);
});
```

You can see [this code on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/odi86/J7CrQ/) (that why I had to slightly adapt your code).